# How to solve this error: android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE?

Tags: app-inventor, google-play-console

I tried uploading my apk which I made using MIT App Inventor in Google Play Console but there this error was shown

"Your app uses the following permission:    `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE`. Apps using this permission in an APK are required to have a private policy set."

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the suggestions from the "error message" and provide a private policy...

See also [Learn how to create a Privacy Policy for your apps](https://community.thunkable.com/t/learn-how-to-create-privacy-policy-for-your-apps/1392?u=taifun)

or just do a Google Search https://www.google.com/search?q=android+private+policy